# Esper query for A followed by B immediately without any other events in between (no matter which event)

Tags: esper, epl

I have to implement the rule, that if A occurs, B hast to occur next without any event in between. Usually I could do this by just using the patter:

```
A->(B and not ...)
```

But I have to implement it very dynamical. That means that I don't know all of the possible events in advance. Does anybody know how i could implement this?
I guess I need something like:

```
A->(B and not any other event)
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267473/esper-statement-to-check-if-a-is-followed-by-b-without-any-other-as-in-between

Answer (score 0):

See this other ticket [Esper statement to check, if A is followed by B without any other As in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267473/esper-statement-to-check-if-a-is-followed-by-b-without-any-other-as-in-between)
It explains the match-recognize.

Here are a few path you can go down in respect to many types of events.

**Create-schema with inherits plus typeof-function**

```
create schema Parent();
create schema A() inherits Parent;
create schema B() inherits Parent;
// now you can treat all events as Parent events
select * from pattern[p=Parent(typeof(p)='A') -> ...] // or match-recognize
```

**Variant stream**

```
create variant schema AnyEventStream as *; // this stream can hold any type of event
insert into AnyEventStream select * from A;
insert into AnyEventStream select * from B;
select * from pattern[p=AnyEventStream(typeof(p)='A') -> ...]  // or match-recognize
```

**Normalize with insert-into**

```
insert into CombinedStream select 'a' as type from A;
insert into CombinedStream select 'b' as type from B;
// now match on CombinedStream
select * from pattern[p=CombinedStream(type='A') -> ...]  // or match-recognize
```

**Make each event a column**

```
create schema CombinedStream(col java.lang.Object);
insert into CombinedStream select a as col from A as a;
insert into CombinedStream select b as col from B as b;
select * from pattern[p=CombinedStream(typeof(col)='...') -> ...]  // or match-recognize
```

You can probably combine some of these approaches. You can also use Java interfaces and abstract classes in replacement of "inherits" since the type system recognizes superclasses/interfaces.

Comment: Thank you very for your reply. I tried your suggestions and making each event a column seams to work pretty well for me.
My only problem is, that i have to get access to the properties of each event to check some conditions.
For example:
````
select * from CombinedStream.win:length(1) where typeof(col)='MachineFailureEvent' and id=1;
````
Until the id-check everything works fine, but the compiler tells me, that the property id is not valid in this stream.. do you have in idea?
Tanke you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very for your reply. I tried your suggestions and making each event a column seams to work pretty well for me.
My only problem is, that i have to get access to the properties of each event to check some conditions.
For example:

```
select * from CombinedStream.win:length(1) where typeof(col)='MachineFailureEvent' and id=1;
```

Until the id-check everything works fine, but the compiler tells me, that the property id is not valid in this stream.. do you have in idea?
Tanke you :)